# Recognizing Padé approximant in Simplify/Refine

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, maple

Having used Maple before, I know for a fact that there we can just type in a function, then separately define its Padé approximant (or Taylor) and then use `simplify` on the approximant and the result will recognize that the latter is the Padé approximation and will simplify it to that. For example :

```
f:=1+z/2*(1+sqrt(1+4/z));
t1:=2+z;
t2:=2+z-1/(2+z);
t3:=2+z-1/(2+z-1/(2+z));
t4:=2+z-1/(2+z-1/(2+z-1/(2+z)));

z:=1/x;                    # maple pade does not seem to expand about infinity

simplify(t1);
simplify(t2);
simplify(t3);
simplify(t4);

with(numapprox);
```

resulting in

```
pade(f,x,[1,1]);
pade(f,x,[2,2]);
pade(f,x,[3,3]);
pade(f,x,[4,4]);
```

where it is important to note that the terms $t1,...,t4$ are the actual Padé approximants. I have searched around in Mathematica but found no equivalent - nor for Padé nor even for Taylor. Is there really none built in? And if not, is there an easy work around in Mathematica? Thanks in advance for answers and comments.

Comment: `PadeApproximant` and `Series`

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Because my goal is not to compute the Padé approximation but rather recognize it once it has been computed.

Comment: (1) These are not uniquely defined, so it would mean the programming environment used by `Simplify` informing the function that, in effect. there is this function defined for which your input might be a Pade approximant. (2) Since this transformation goes in the opposite direction, it would require an inert form of `PadeApproximant` so as not to immediately reevaluate to the input expression.

Comment: They are not uniquely defined, but that's just up to a common multiplication factor in both numerator and denominator - and as factoring and simplifying is something Mathematica can do, I haven't thought of this as such an issue. 

But I take it sa there are indeed no available functions that would do this recognition.